# Get Current User Login ID in OTRS

Tags: perl, otrs

I want to get the login ID of the current user in `OTRS`. I dont know nothing about the Framework and Structure of `OTRS`. Tried to Google a lot but as I dont have any background in `Perl` I didnt understand anything. Just want to know How can I print or return Login ID of current user in `OTRS`.

Comment: where do you need that? are you writing your own add-on?

Comment: @MiguelPrz I need to Get the Current loginID and search that LoginID in a Remote Database, then get the LoginID and Password from that Remote database and concatenate it to a url. Not a whole new addon just a simple Hack. want to do all this in a new Customer Menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to write your own frontend module. From within the frontend module the active customer user is available as `$Self->{UserID}` and you can use it to call the remote webservice.

You can use remote web services via the WebUserAgent object.

Please note that writing OTRS modules is fairly easy but does require some effort. The question you had is really very basic and you could have solved it just by looking at other code in the framework.

Comment: Thank You. I don't Have any Idea How `OTRS` works. Just trying to Get Over wit it.